# How to define a Typescript function that swaps values of two object properties by name, with check of type compatibility?

Tags: typescript, types, swap

I'm trying to define a function that swaps values of two properties on an object given their names, but I would like compiler to check types compatibility (or at least check both properties to have same type):

```js
function swap<T, TKey1 extends keyof T, TKey2 extends keyof T>(obj: T, key1: TKey1, key2: TKey2): void{
    let temp = obj[key1];
    obj[key1] = obj[key2]; 
    obj[key2] = temp;
}


let obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: ""
}

swap(obj, "a", "b");    // good, both are numbers
swap(obj, "a", "c");    // should not compile, swapping number with string
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20swap%3CT%2C%20TKey1%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%20TKey2%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key1%3A%20TKey1%2C%20key2%3A%20TKey2)%3A%20void%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20temp%20%3D%20obj%5Bkey1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20obj%5Bkey1%5D%20%3D%20obj%5Bkey2%5D%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20obj%5Bkey2%5D%20%3D%20temp%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aswap(obj%2C%20%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22)%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20goood%2C%20both%20are%20numbers%0D%0Aswap(obj%2C%20%22a%22%2C%20%22c%22)%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20not%20compile%2C%20swapping%20number%20with%20string)

I got some result with the following, but it requires obj to be passed twice.

```js
function swap<T,
    TKey1 extends keyof T,
    TKey2 extends keyof T,
    TIn extends { [p in TKey1|TKey2]: T[TKey1] } >(_:T, obj: TIn, key1: TKey1, key2: TKey2): void{
    let temp = <any>obj[key1];
    obj[key1] = <any>obj[key2]; 
    obj[key2] = temp;
}


let obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: ""
}

swap(obj, obj, "a", "b");    // good, both are numbers
swap(obj, obj, "a", "c");    // error, as expected
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20swap%3CT%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TKey1%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TKey2%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TIn%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bp%20in%20TKey1%7CTKey2%5D%3A%20T%5BTKey1%5D%20%7D%20%3E(_%3AT%2C%20obj%3A%20TIn%2C%20key1%3A%20TKey1%2C%20key2%3A%20TKey2)%3A%20void%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20temp%20%3D%20%3Cany%3Eobj%5Bkey1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20obj%5Bkey1%5D%20%3D%20%3Cany%3Eobj%5Bkey2%5D%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20obj%5Bkey2%5D%20%3D%20temp%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aswap(obj%2C%20obj%2C%20%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22)%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20good%2C%20both%20are%20numbers%0D%0Aswap(obj%2C%20obj%2C%20%22a%22%2C%20%22c%22)%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20error%2C%20as%20expected)

Alternatively, I can achieve desired result with conditional types if I return a function, but it is too easy to forget second call.

```js
function swap<T,
    TKey1 extends keyof T,
    TKey2 extends keyof T>(obj: T, key1: TKey1, key2: TKey2):
                                            T[TKey1] extends T[TKey2] ? T[TKey2] extends T[TKey1] 
                                                ? () => void
                                                : never : never {

    return <any>(() => {
        let temp = <any>obj[key1];
        obj[key1] = <any>obj[key2];
        obj[key2] = temp;
    });
}


let obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: ""
}

swap(obj, "a", "b")();    // good, both are numbers
swap(obj, "a", "c")();    // error, as expected
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20swap%3CT%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TKey1%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TKey2%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key1%3A%20TKey1%2C%20key2%3A%20TKey2)%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20T%5BTKey1%5D%20extends%20T%5BTKey2%5D%20%3F%20T%5BTKey2%5D%20extends%20T%5BTKey1%5D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20never%20%3A%20never%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3Cany%3E(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20temp%20%3D%20%3Cany%3Eobj%5Bkey1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%5Bkey1%5D%20%3D%20%3Cany%3Eobj%5Bkey2%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%5Bkey2%5D%20%3D%20temp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aswap(obj%2C%20%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22)()%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20good%2C%20both%20are%20numbers%0D%0Aswap(obj%2C%20%22a%22%2C%20%22c%22)()%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20error%2C%20as%20expected)

Is it possible to simplify above examples? Can I maybe supply some type instead of `never` that will indicate error to type system?

P.S. I know about `[obj.a, obj.b] = [obj.b, obj.a];` , but would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, they key turned out to be filtering the second key with advanced types.

Source code available: https://github.com/IKoshelev/ts-typing-util/blob/master/src/Swap.ts

NPM installation `npm i ts-typing-util`

```js
export type SwappableKeys<T, TKey1 extends keyof T> = Exclude<{
    [key in keyof T]:
    /**/ T[key] extends T[TKey1]
    /**/ ? T[TKey1] extends T[key]
    /*      */ ? key
    /*      */ : never
    /**/ : never;

}[keyof T], TKey1>;

/**
 * Swap prop values with a check that values have compatible type
 * @example
 * const t = {
 *   a: 1,
 *   b: 2,
 *   c: '',
 *   c1: '',
 *   d: { a: 5 },
 *   e: { a: 6 },
 *   f: { b: 7 },
 *   g: { a: '' }
 * }
 *
 * swap(t, 'a', 'b');
 * swap(t, 'a', 'c'); //error
 * swap(t, 'b', 'c'); //error
 * swap(t, 'a', 'a'); //error
 * swap(t, 'c', 'c1');
 * swap(t, 'd','e');
 * swap(t, 'd','f'); //error
 * swap(t, 'd','g'); //error
 **/
export function swap<T, TKey1 extends keyof T>(inst: T, key1: TKey1, key2: SwappableKeys<T, TKey1>): void {

    const buff = inst[key1] as any;
    inst[key1] = inst[key2] as any;
    inst[key2] = buff;

}
```

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=40&ssc=2&pln=34&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKB3AhmMWBGANsANLCIDOAPACoA0cNZiAjHKDMAHYAmFcAa3IQAZowB8cALxwAoiADGhAK49gVAN4AoOLrgBtIYjgBLLoOFiaAXQBcOvQHoAVM8eND5a%20xCde-Gn0mchZrB10XNzgAfg9g1m8Obj4PIzC9OBcM3SjYo3DM52y4KNs4LmAAN2AoAsj3MorqqABuLS0AX09EUUZrBniWcTatSJ0izBw4MCgIMDhKrBVgfgwTGAALOCw4BQ3gBQEEDax4ReX%20E%20rdiABbPBgTIlQkFHG4AAFQLHvid4UIFwKPB4DJtCU9Fgyiw6O9dPgygAmWEQ3QKMoAcgxKKKaJYmOxcLgPDKGm2ZQArHAOji9MBSeS4AA2am03QiBkIuAAdlZRIA5gyoXAsdT3h1xu8KNgwAAKGAMDFYbEi-AYgCUbQh0pw8sVysVCg1LUyjhqs1q2pletVKoxRs1pvN0Cl1oVIoNHuNTqgFtduvd9rtChYxv9csDPGxGOAYatAcVUboGJE3scZt9LvjEcT0f5aYzfpKbi0oEgsDgImUXAUj0BcB1YFoA2YbCS-gsPSs4llZmBZXonfxjFbDCMiLKk1wBGIzGog8G4nVZUqEBMPDg2gKAKB8HwyhEYhkfZg3VC234WC4iC1ehPZ%208x933UR3iwl%20vt909-Hj7g%208PEYJS0HdgQQaRNwKYUYQKLlkW3AkUT0ENEIKElN0ZKkaQKekMOFFlsIyYBhzJYUAGY%20QyDkMK5XlCL0QU8IJPkJVeVApzwZ453kH4wGIGQOJnUhyGoNjekjDFhnaRsbSVO01U1LQZMDT0g0ddNnVqZTFTVQ0C00pS3X1O1lXUwsXW0kUjUNUNFMsjEkxFWM7KMkVHJTfTMy01yHLtfMzIMoA)